# Inheriting a superclass and having overridden methods called automatically

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to implement a base class (let's call it Engine). And it has `Start` and `Update` functions.

Then have subclasses inherit from this base class (so they implement the `Start` and `Update` functions). And after implementing these methods, have these methods called at the correct times automatically without having to manage instances of the subclass? (In this case, whenever `Engine` calls `Start`, the subclass should call `Start` too.) Is this even possible?

To clarify, I'm thinking about how Unity implemented `MonoBehaviour`:

```
public class MonoBehaviour 
{
  // Unknown Implementation...but this is what it looks like in my head
   private void OnGamestartup()
   {
        Start();
   }
   void Start()
   {
   }

   private void OnGameUpdate()
   {
        Update();
   }
   void Update()
   {
   }
}

// And by dragging this onto the GameObject, the methods are called at the correct times (Update everyframe and start at game start up)
// Hmm, I'm guessing the component nature of the Unity engine is somehow maintaining an instance of EngineSubclass? 

//The following class is what gets autogenerated if you create a script in Unity
public class EngineSubclass : MonoBehaviour 
{
   void Start()
   {
   }
   void Update()
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: If you have two methods in a class hierarchy with the same signature then they will hide eachother. So with this in mind it isn't even possible to do what you want, unless you cast the object to the correct (sub)class halfway throughout execution. Perhaps you can clarify your situation by providing a more concrete context (preferably with code)?

Comment: *Which* subclass should call start? Or which *instance* of the subclass should call start? Your question is pretty unclear - I *suspect* you're unclear in your own mind about how it would work too.  Think about how many objects you're expecting there to be, and of what types - how do they know about each other, and how are they related?

Comment: I'm with Jon here; I can't figure out what you're asking. Try describing the business problem you're actually trying to solve, rather than the mechanism that you think will solve it.

Comment: I don't get it. don't you just want to do like: `void Start(){base.Start();}`

Comment: Right, that's what I was thinking too. 

Sure, if it helps, I'm just trying to figure out how UnityEngine's Monobehaviour class is implemented. (https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) . It seems like just by inheriting MonoBehaviour and implementing Start and Update is enough to have them automatically called.

Comment: Unity uses a lot of reflection so it kind of circumvents the whole inheritance thing. As far as I know it uses a convention based approach in a lot of places so that it can discover methods on your objects and cache delegates for those operations

Comment: Just to check - when you inherit Monobehaviour, what does the signature look like for the `Start` method? Does it contain an override keyword?

Comment: It seems to me that he is simply asking for virtual methods.

Comment: No, it's not virtual methods though it would first appear that way - if you look at the signature of the example in the `Monobehavior` documentation (c# version) there is no override for the `Start` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that Unity uses a lot of reflection and delegate caching so I'd make a good guess that it is simply using reflection to check if you have implemented a method on your subclass

It will most likely look for all types that subclass `Monobehavior` and use `Type.GetMethod()` to determine if you have implemented the method. It then probably creates a delegate for that method and caches it (for performance reasons, reflection is not perfomant).

Looking at the example on the Unity docs confirms this is the most likely case:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour {
    private GameObject target;
    void Start() {
        target = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
    }
}
```

There is no virtual method use here (since no `override`) so reflection is likely the answer

**Edit:** to mirror your hypothetical class this is what it more likely looks like (a **very** contrived example):

```
// Part of unity - an internal class that you wouldn't see
public class UnityInternalGameEngineClass
{
   private void OnEngineStartup()
   {
        DiscoverBehaviors();
   }

   private void DiscoverBehaviours() 
   {
      foreach(Type t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(x=>x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MonoBehavior)))
      {
          // Find method
          MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod("Start");
          delegateCachingSystem.Add(m.CreateDelegate(blahblah));
      }
   }

   private void GameStart() 
   {
     // Loop though all behaviors and start them
   }

   private void GameUpdate()
   {
     // Loop though all behaviors and update them
   }
}
```

(obviously the above is a load of rubbish that wont compile but it gives you an idea of the likely mechanism)

Comment: Ah intersting. Just to clarify, so you mean, MonoBehaviour is searching all the implemented classes for their Start and Update methhods using Type.GetMethod("Start") and calling them?

Comment: Well yes, but likely another engine component is doing that - there is likely a whole caching system, like I said, reflection is very slow. Most likely all your custom `Monobehavior` types are discovered when the engine starts and delegates are created and cached per type. From then on everything is delegate based (function pointers) which are as fast as directly calling a method in most cases. The Monobehavior class will most likely just have a skeleton implementation which determines if your subclass is doing certain things - it probably doesn't do anything.

Comment: Since Unity is component based and a lot of the components follow this pattern, there is most likely a central system which governs the delegate creation, caching, calling of these methods in the right places etc etc. (this is all speculation though, but it's somewhat educated speculation)

Comment: There's some good info on using delegate caching here: http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/11/reflection-slow-or-faster-demonstration.html

Comment: Ah interesting, but it seems a little contrived? Thought there might be a language feature behind it that I'm not familiar with haha.

Comment: I'm not sure why they chose this route over anything else, but I can imagine that there's a good reason. Maybe it has something to do with being able to script in multiple languages in Unity, or it could be for compatibility and maintainability reasons (a change to an interface can break a lot of functionality, but if reflection is used there is no concrete coupling). I'd post on the Unity forums and see if you can get a good answer from the devs

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a the [NVI pattern](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/NVI.aspx).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I thought it was better to provide the name of the pattern that handles the scenario instead of just a piece of code which doesn't explain the underlying concept. I'll try to provide both kind of answers next time.